# How can I collect unspecified command line options when using Python's `argh`?

Tags: python, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments, argh

With the Python CLI library [`argh`](https://github.com/neithere/argh) I want to write a wrapper tool. This wrapper tool is suppose to read the two options `-a` and `-b` and to pass all other options to a function (which then calls the wrapped UNIX tool with the left-over options via `subprocess`).

I have experimented with `dispatch`'s  parameter `skip_unknown_args`:

```
def wrapper(a=True, b=False):
    print("Enter wrapper")
    # 1. process a and b 
    # 2. call_unix_tool(left-over-args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argh.ArghParser()
    argh.set_default_command(parser, wrapper)
    argh.dispatch(parser, skip_unknown_args=True)
```

However the  program still does exit when it encounters unknown options and it does not enter the function `wrapper` as needed. Additionally I don't know where the unknown/skipped arguments are stored, so that I can pass them to the UNIX tool.

How can I tell `argh` to go into `wrapper` with the skipped arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this with `skip_unknown_args=True`, because [as @georgexsh pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46912858/65889) the `argh` library doesn't seem to behave sensibly with that option. However you can provide your own parser class which injects the unknown arguments into the normal namespace:

```
class ArghParserWithUnknownArgs(argh.ArghParser):
    def parse_args(self, args=None, namespace=None):
        namespace = namespace or ArghNamespace()
        (namespace_obj, unknown_args) = super(ArghParserWithUnknownArgs, self).parse_known_args(args=args, namespace=namespace)
        namespace_obj.__dict__['unknown_args'] = unknown_args
        return namespace_obj
```

Note that this class' `parse_args` method calls `ArgParser`'s `parse_`**`known`**`_args` method!

With this class defined you can write the wrapper code following way:

```
def wrapper(a=True, b=False, unknown_args={}):
    print("a = %s, b = %s" % (a,b))
    print("unknown_args = %s" % unknown_args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = ArghParserWithUnknownArgs()
    argh.set_default_command(parser, wrapper)
    argh.dispatch(parser)
```

In your main function `wrapper` you can access all unknown arguments via the parameter `unknown_args` and pass this on to your subprocess command

ps: In order to keep the help message tidy decorate `wrapper` with

```
@argh.arg('--unknown_args', help=argparse.SUPPRESS)
```

Addendum: I created an enhanced version of the parser and compiled it into a ready-to-use module. Find it on [Github](https://github.com/halloleo/arghex).

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a bug.

when `skip_unknown_args=True`, here `namespace_obj` is a tuple, with a namespace object and remaining args:

```
(Pdb) p namespace_obj
    (ArghNamespace(_functions_stack=[<function wrapper at 0x105cb5e18>], a=False, b=True), ['-c'])
```

underlying `_get_function_from_namespace_obj` expects an unary one:

```
154     function = _get_function_from_namespace_obj(namespace_obj)
...
191     if isinstance(namespace_obj, ArghNamespace):
```

I checked [its coressponding issue and unittest](https://github.com/neithere/argh/issues/57), no idea what is the legitmate behivour the author expects, have dropped a comment there as well.

why not use `argparse` directly?

Comment: Thanks @georgexsh. Indeed this seems to be a bug. I  try at the moment to work around it by using my own ˋdispatchˋ function which injects the unknown args as a list to ˋnamespace_objˋ, but it is pretty cumbersome. Might instead try to move this functionality into a custom parser object...

Comment: Mmmh, I really want to use `argh`: It is so much cleaner for the main work. I have drawn up something which I will post as an answer using `argh`.